# fill the width from right to left instead of default left to right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this rating star system work as right to left and it just works fine but as soon as it gets a point like 3.5 which requires half full of a star, it fill the star with half width of the image used from left side of it.

I'm wondering how I can make the star to fill the blanked star from right instead of left side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try adding

```
ul.lising_rating li {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Comment: He'd only still have to reposition the image by it's width

Comment: @Sohail @icke There isn't any markup shown in the question, so can you tell me if `ul.listing_rating li` is the element which is going to be filled/filled by child elements. I have a `div` and i want its children (three `div`s displayed in a line)to be rendered from Right-to-Left. I have explained the scenerio with an [SSCCE here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144400/is-it-possible-to-render-inline-children-of-a-div-right-to-left-instead-of-the)