# Is it possible to render (inline) children of a div Right-To-Left instead of the default Left-To-Right?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Normally the elements of an HTML markup appear in the order they are written in the markup file, and the inline elements appear from left to right.

**But I want the children of a certain `div`** (only, NOT all the elements of the entire page) **to appear from right to left.**

In case you wonder why it is needed, I want to do this to solve the following problem:

**PROBLEM:**

**[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/fqoxpn9e/)**

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 826px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: table;
  background-color: #003b80;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left-cell {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: chocolate;
}
.right-cell {
  background-color: darkslategrey
}
.step-container {
  max-height: 200px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.right-cell .step-container {
  margin-top: 125px;
}
.content-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  /*border: 5px solid blue;*/
  font-size: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
  background-color: dodgerblue
}
.right-cell .content-box {
  background-color: darkturquoise
}
.middle-cell {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 1.5px;
  font-size: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}
.number-outer-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
.left-cell .number-outer-container {
  /*margin-left:39px;*/
}
.number-inner-container {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.number-banner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: crimson;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.notch-outer-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.left-cell .notch-outer-container {
  margin-right: 24px;
}
.right-cell .notch-outer-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.notch-inner-container {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.notch {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}
.left-face-notch {
  border-right: 15px solid #520f23;
}
.right-face-notch {
  border-left: 15px solid #571780;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">


  <div class="cell left-cell" align="left">

    <div class="step-container">
      <div class="content-box"></div>



      <div class="notch-outer-container">
        <div class="notch-inner-container">
          <div class="right-face-notch notch"></div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="number-outer-container">
        <div class="number-inner-container">
          <div class="number-banner"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="cell middle-cell"></div>



  <div class="cell right-cell" align="right">

    <div class="step-container">

      <div class="number-outer-container">
        <div class="number-inner-container">
          <div class="number-banner"></div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="notch-outer-container">
        <div class="notch-inner-container">
          <div class="left-face-notch notch"></div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="content-box"></div>

    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

In this SSCCE, inside `.left-cell .step-container`, I have three elements appearing on the same line: `.content-box`, `.notch-outer-container`, and `.number-outer-container`; and to make the `.notch` appear to be overlapping the `right-cell` by 50% of its width, I gave `.number-outer-container` a `position:absolute;` and `.notch-outer-container` a `margin-right` which pushes the `number-outer-container` to right side to an extent that it *appears to be overlapping* the (`.middle-cell` and) `right-cell` by 50% of it's width.

**The problem is that in the `.right-cell`, this strategy is NOT working.** First the `.number-right-container` appears and still it is `absolute`, I can not give it a `left` property with value relative to its parent (*otherwise I would try a `left:-25px` to make it appear `25px` behind the left edge of its parent, because it has `width:50px;`*). Then the `.notch` is hidden below it...

So I am thinking about finding a way through which I can get the elements render from RTL (Right To Left) rather than LTR only inside `.right-cell` on the page. **So that I can follow the same strategy I have used for the `.left-cell`, in the `.right-cell.`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's numerous ways to achieve what you want using either `flex`ing, `float`s or other options, but I'd say one of the easiest ways, if the rest of the layout works as you want it to, is to use the `direction` attribute.

```css
div {
  direction: rtl;
}
div div {
  display: inline-block;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>first</div>
  <div>second</div>
  <div>last</div>
</div>
```